# How to retrieve raster's metadata from PostGIS, using Python?

Tags: python, postgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, psycopg2

I am working on a PostGIS database, and I would like to store GeoTIFF raster images in some of my tables. Currently, I use `GDAL` to convert / read my images, and `psycopg2` to connect to a SQL server. However, when I want to get a raster from the database, the metadata is missing.
I am using `ST_FromGDALRaster` to store raster data to the database (in bytes format), and `ST_AsGDALRaster(my_tile, 'GTiff')` to retrieve it.

#### Here is a code snippet that illustrates my issue:

First, let's create a naive `gdal.Dataset` object using numpy.

```py
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, osr

def create_ds():
    # GeoTIFF data (N_band, N_x, N_y)
    data = np.ones((3, 1000, 1000))  # naive data
    epsg = 3857  # mercator
    # Coordinates
    X = [-10, 10]
    Y = [-10, 10]
    # bbox
    Nb, Nx, Ny = data.shape
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = np.min(X), np.min(Y), np.max(X), np.max(Y)
    xres = (xmax - xmin) / float(Nx)
    yres = (ymax - ymin) / float(Ny)
    geotransform = (xmin, xres, 0, ymax, 0, -yres)
    # Temp file, so nothing is saved on the disk
    vsimem = '/vsimem/temp'
    # Create a gdal.Dataset
    ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(vsimem, Ny, Nx, Nb, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
    ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
    # Write data for all bands
    for band in range(Nb):
        ds.GetRasterBand(band + 1).WriteArray(data[band])
    
    return ds
```

```py
# Create the dataset

ds = create_ds()

# Modify the metadata
ds.SetMetadataItem('NewMetaKey', 'NewValue')
ds.SetMetadataItem('NewMetaKey2', 'NewValue2')

ds.GetMetadata()

# Out: {'NewMetaKey': 'NewValue', 'NewMetaKey2': 'NewValue2'}
```

Then, let's implement a function to convert `gdal.Dataset` to bytes, so it will be easier to store in PostGIS:

```py
def to_bytes(ds):
    # use temp files
    vsimem = '/vsimem/temp'
    gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff").CreateCopy(vsimem, ds)
    f = gdal.VSIFOpenL(vsimem, 'rb')
    gdal.VSIFSeekL(f, 0, 2)  # seek to end
    size = gdal.VSIFTellL(f)
    gdal.VSIFSeekL(f, 0, 0)  # seek to beginning
    dbytes = gdal.VSIFReadL(1, size, f)
    gdal.Unlink(vsimem)
    return dbytes
```

```py
# Convert the dataset to bytes

dbytes = to_bytes(ds)
```

Then, convert bytes data to a `gdal.Dataset`:

```py
def from_bytes(dbytes):
    vsimem = '/vsimem/temp'
    gdal.FileFromMemBuffer(vsimem, bytes(dbytes))
    ds = gdal.Open(vsimem)
    gdal.Unlink(vsimem)
    return ds
```

```py
# Convert bytes to a dataset

ds2 = from_bytes(dbytes)

# Get the metadata
ds2.GetMetadata()

# Out: {'AREA_OR_POINT': 'Area', 'NewMetaKey': 'NewValue', 'NewMetaKey2': 'NewValue2'}
```

Next, add the data to a PostGIS table, named 'table':

```py
import psycopg2 as psql

with psql.connect(**config) as conn: # To autocommit / rollback
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO table(my_tile) VALUES (ST_FromGDALRaster(%(byte)s))", {'byte': dbytes})
```

Then, retrieve the data:

```py
conn = psql.connect(**config)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SELECT ST_AsGDALRaster(my_tile, 'GTiff') FROM table;")

ds3 = from_bytes(bytes(curs.fetchone()[0]))

# Get the metadata
ds3.GetMetadata()

# Out: {'AREA_OR_POINT': 'Area'}
```

#### And at the end, the metadata does not match the initial values.

How can I modify my code so the metadata is not changed ?